# How to make a good recurring function in js

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to make a fallback function that imitates Promise for ie and whatnot

I have the following code:

```
function goPromise(nr){
    console.time("promise");
    var sum = 0;
    var prom = function(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve){
            sum = sum + nr;
            nr = nr-1;
            resolve();
        });
    }
    var doThat = function(){
        if(nr > 0){
            prom().then(function(){
                nr = nr - 1;
                doThat()
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log(sum);
            console.timeEnd("promise");
        }
    }
    doThat();
}

function goNormal(nr){
    console.time("normal");
    var sum = 0;
    var x = function(){
        if(nr > 0){
            sum = sum + nr;
            nr = nr -1;
            x();
        }
        else {
            console.timeEnd("normal")
        }
    }
    x();
}
```

The goNormal works fine and faster than goPromise. That until i give it a big number like 50.000. In which case it gives me this

[image: screenshot]

What does promise have that it can do this stuff no matter how many times?

And how can I implement it in vanilla js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A promise is a callback in the future, thus it does *NOT* recurse. It's like using window.setTimeout (which would solve your issue in the goNormal instance). In the case of the promise, you've set it up and thus the current execution of the "doThat" function actually terminates.

As there is a promise involved, which results in a callback in the future, you'd expect it to be slower. You'll find that using setTimeout will also slow your execution plan down.

The example given is contrived as recursion is not required, however, I get your point. Is there a particular problem you're trying to solve or is this academic?

See my example code below with setTimeout.

```
function goNormal(nr){
    console.time("normal");
    var sum = 0;
    var x = function(){
        if(nr > 0){
            sum = sum + nr;
            nr = nr -1;
            window.setTimeout(x, 10);
        }
        else {
            console.timeEnd("normal")
        }
    }
    x();
}
```

Comment: this is academic. i want to make a function that imitates a small part of Promise

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requestAnimationFrame` in order to call the function again, and again, and again ... at roughly 60fps intervals ... and cause it to stop until it meets a certain condition.  See simple example:

```js
function recurring() {
  var t1 = performance.now();
  
  if (t1 > 1000) {
    console.log("Done!");
  } else {
    console.log("Still going ... ");
    window.requestAnimationFrame(recurring);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(recurring);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/js-recursion.html#4) offers two nice solutions that allow you to execute a recursive function as if it was a simple loop.

The first one, the "Trampoline" method:

```js
function trampoline(cb) {
    while (cb && cb instanceof Function) {
        cb = cb();
    }

    return cb;
};

function goNormalT(nr) {
    console.time("normal");
    var sum = 0;

    var x = function(){
        if(nr > 0){
            sum = sum + nr;
            nr = nr -1;
            return x.bind(null, nr);
        }
        else {
            console.timeEnd("normal");
            return null;
        }
    }

    return trampoline(x.bind(null));
};

goNormalT(50000);
```

And a second one, a "Tail Call Optimizer":

```js
function tco(f) {
  var value;
  var active = false;
  var accumulated = [];

  return function accumulator() {
    accumulated.push(arguments);

    if (!active) {
      active = true;

      while (accumulated.length) {
        value = f.apply(this, accumulated.shift());
      }

      active = false;

      return value;
    }
  }
}

function goNormal(nr) {
  console.time("normal");
  var sum = 0;

  var x = tco(function() {
    if (nr > 0) {
      sum = sum + nr;
      nr = nr - 1;
      return x();
    } else {
      console.timeEnd("normal");
      return null;
    }
  });

  return x();
};

goNormal(50000);
```

The second one being a bit more sophisticated implementation of the first method.

If the ways these work are hard to grasp, make sure to check the article for an in depth explanation.